# Why new Array(4).join("ha") yields "hahahaha" and not "undefinedhaundefinedha .."

Tags: javascript

Why `new Array(4).join("ha")` yields "hahaha" and not "*undefined*ha*undefined*ha .." ?

```
var arr = new Array(4);
alert( arr[0] ); //  produces `undefined`
```

Answer (score 5):

Elements of the array that are `undefined` or `null` are converted to the empty string. [It's right there in the documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#Description)

> If an element is undefined or null, it is converted to the empty string.